# How I can make synchronize between my LKM and the Linux kernel for shared data structure?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm developing a LKM(Loadable Kernel Module) in Linux.
What the LKM want to is traverse all process information through TCB(i.e. task_strct).

I'm wondering if TCB data structure is updating while the LKM traverse the data structure.

That is, during LKM traverse TCB data structure, the data structure is can be updating because of a process is termination or creationg.
How I can make synchronize between my LKM and the Linux kernel that keeps updating the TCB data structure in SMP or Non SMP Linux system?
//Daum

Comment: You should check if a mutex/lock exists for accessing such information in mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
I think you can traverse the process list via below sample code

struct task_struct *task;
rcu_read_lock();                                                    
for_each_process(task) {                                             
      task_lock(task);                                             

      /* do something with your task :) */

      task_unlock(task);                                           
}                                                                    
rcu_read_unlock();
```

Reference :: [how to iterate over PCB's to show information in a Linux Kernel Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560229/how-to-iterate-over-pcbs-to-show-information-in-a-linux-kernel-module)